# Custom sort array to declare which elements should be first based on another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have visited similar question here but not getting what i want in php. Suppose i have 2 arrays.  All checking should be case insensitive. say Field0 is same as field0 or fiEld1 is same as Field1.

```
array1 is array(
"0"=>"field0",
"1"=>"field1",
"2"=>"field2",
"3"=>"field3",
);

array2 is array(
"0"=>"field3",
"1"=>"field2",
"2"=>"field0",
"3"=>"field1",
"4"=>"field6",
"5"=>"field5",
);
```

Now I want array2 to be sorted based on array1 like the following:

```
array2 is array(
"0"=>"field0",
"1"=>"field1",
"2"=>"field2",
"3"=>"field3",
"4"=>"field6",
"5"=>"field5",
);
```

look here array1 has 4 elements so array2 should be sorted based exactly 4 elements of array1  and rest 2 element (index 4,5 of array2) should  as it is in array2 before.

Comment: This isn't a great [mcve] because the first four elements to be sorted as the first four elements.  By happenstance, jgroenen's seems correct, but will not be in other circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [array_intersect](http://php.net/array_intersect) combined with [array_diff](http://php.net/array_diff):

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    "0"=>"field0",
    "1"=>"field1",
    "2"=>"field2",
    "3"=>"field3",
);

$array2 = array(
    "0"=>"field3",
    "1"=>"field2",
    "2"=>"field0",
    "3"=>"field1",
    "4"=>"field6",
    "5"=>"field5",
);


$array3 = array_merge(
    array_intersect($array1, $array2), 
    array_diff($array2, $array1)
);

var_dump($array3);
```

**Update**

For a case insensitive approach, use [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map) to guarantee all entries in both arrays are lower-cased:

```
$array3 = array_map('strtolower', $array1);
$array4 = array_map('strtolower', $array2);

$array5 = array_merge(
    array_intersect($array3, $array4), 
    array_diff($array4, $array3)
);

var_dump($array5);
```

Comment: if i change the case of the value of array1 or array2 then sort will be changed. could you make it case insensitive?

Comment: Do you also want to preserve the original case of the arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that array 2 is always bigger than array 1:

```
$array2 = array_merge($array1, array_diff($array2, $array1));
```

Answer (score -2):

It's really easy :

```
$array = $array1 + $array2
```

Comment: This will not work, as this only computes the union between the two arrays. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: Sorry, but :$array1 = array(
"0"=>"field0",
"1"=>"field1",
"2"=>"field2",
"3"=>"field3",
);

$array2 = array(
"0"=>"field3",
"1"=>"field2",
"2"=>"field0",
"3"=>"field1",
"4"=>"field6",
"5"=>"field5",
);

var_dump($array1 + $array2);


[code]
array(6) {
  [0] =>
  string(6) "field0"
  [1] =>
  string(6) "field1"
  [2] =>
  string(6) "field2"
  [3] =>
  string(6) "field3"
  [4] =>
  string(6) "field6"
  [5] =>
  string(6) "field5"
}
[/code]

Comment: It may work in this one case, but is relying on a lot of assumptions about the input data.  perhaps the onus should be on the OP to provide a bit more insight, but in general this will not work. See the first example in the man page I linked to.

Comment: You should probably also explain possible problems with using this method if the input happens to not work out so nicely.

Comment: The major problem is that the union operator works on array keys and not array values, and both arrays are (basically) numerically indexed